# Canonical Redirect on the server only

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting, web-config

I can redirect all domain.com-s on a www.domain.com and it's working on the server like a charm:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.domain\.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But is has one side effect - it is also working when I am on a testing environment, like on localhost and it always redirects on a production server.

How is it possible to add some condition that is would work on the server only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved using a second condition requesting the host to be a `domain.com` sub-domain:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain\.com$" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.domain\.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

(note that you were missing a `\` in your condition and that `redirectType="Permanent"` is optional)